# Basic JS question: how to do 'else, load javascript'

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad

I have a bit of Javascript I want to the iPad/iPhone to ignore, but for other browsers to read. The JS is:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.anchor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've found some code on this site to target a particular device, as follows:

```
<script>
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
   // iPad or iPhone
}
else {
   // Anything else
}
</script>
```

I'm a JavaScript newbie and wouldn't know the syntax to place the script after the // Anything else comment... any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why the iPad and iPhone, specifically?  What about other mobile browsers?  Perhaps there's a better approach that you haven't thought of?

Comment: The Javascript is for a jQuery auto smooth scroll. It works really well on PC/Mac but on iPhone/iPad it's quite clunky and I think would be best if it was omitted. You have a good point with other mobile browsers actually... is there a way I can target them all in one go?

Comment: Target functionalities, not browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't test for the browser, **test for the functionalities** it offers.

If there's a function which is not supported by all the browsers, don't test for which browsers don't support it because what if it supports it in the future?

Do something like this instead:

```
if (nonStandardFunction) {
    nonStandardFunction();
}
```

That way, any browser which supports it will execute it, and you don't care which ones do or don't.

You can also add the functionality yourself:

```
window.nonStandardFunction = window.nonStandardFunction || function () {      
    // your implementation
};
```

---

If on the other hand you specifically don't want an `i<Device>` to access it, test for the user agent.

Here's an example of what you can do:

```
var addJS = function (file) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
      script= document.createElement("script");

  script.type = "text/javascript"; // redundant
  script.src = file;
  head.appendChild(script);
}, userAgent = navigator.userAgent,
   isNotiDevice = !(userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i));

if (isNotiDevice) {
    addJS('scripts/jquery.anchor.js');  
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the iPhone and iPad support the function, they just don't do a good job at executing it... userAgent is what I have in the original code - we'd be happy knowing the scroll is ignored on iPad/iPhone due to their popularity, so is there a way to apply my original JS into the code in my original post? Thanks in advance

Comment: So either identify the i<device>s manually with the UA or roll your own implementation using the sample I provided in my answer.

Comment: This is where I get confused, sorry... I don't know how to say 'load a JS file' in Javascript, I only know how to do it in HTML. Please could you advise the syntax? Thanks,

Comment: Here are 4 examples of how you can load a JavaScript programmatically: http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for the link. Would something like this solve my problem? [sorry, the four space indent to make my post look like code function doesnt seem to be working for me on this post]

    <script language="javascript">
    window.nonStandardFunction = window.nonStandardFunction || 
    function () {      
    document.write("<script src='scripts/jquery.anchor.js'>
    <\/script>");
    };
    </script>

Comment: No.  The reason I provided that example is because I wanted to show how you can add functionality yourself if it's not available.  I will write an example for you on how you can conditionally add a JavaScript file.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/s5KmA/
I didn't test what I wrote but that's a way you can include a JS file manually.

Comment: Your response is appreciated, however the scrolling effect is disabled on my Mac when this code is in place. Time's short for me on this one, I have to launch the website in around an hour... think I'm going to have to accept that the scrolling effect is slightly stuttery on the iPad I guess? Not the end of the world. Would be better for that to be stuttery than for it to not work at all on desktops/laptops.

Comment: Heh you need to launch this in an hour?
Can you show me the exact code you are using?

Comment: Yep, I'm on holiday from tomorrow and my company wants the new site up before I go... what timing huh! Sure, this is what I'm working with: http://www.adaptdesign.com/NEWSITE/NEWINDEX.htm the script in question starts on line 52.

Comment: Heh, you copied and pasted my code directly in the page...
The `isNotiDevice` variable does not exist...I made that up.

Change your code to this: http://jsfiddle.net/s5KmA/1/

Comment: Thank you, will put this in now and try it on the iPad / new Firefox.

Comment: No worries; if you still have problems, don't hesitate to comment back :-)

Comment: Works a treat Andreas, really appreciate all of your help. It will be live on www.adaptdesign.com in less than hour. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hmmm! Quickly, any idea why the scroll won't work on Safari??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you could possibly use

```
   <script id="someID" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and then

```
   document.getElementById('someID').src= 'script.js';
```

And just tailor it within your if statement for a specific browser.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed this comment - this is exactly what I was after. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The issue with this is that you would need a predefined container for each script you want to add.

Comment: @Chris, don't forget you can mark the correct answer by clicking the check/tick on the left ;)

Comment: @Andreas Your answer was clearly better (I'm not even a web developer :P) but @Chris is a beginner so, ya know.

Comment: Turns out this method seems to exclude the latest Firefox, so I'm going to have to look into Andreas' method. is 'nonStandardFunction' a term you have used for an example Andreas or is it JS lingo?

Comment: @Chris Are you sure it's not your if-statement that's the problem?

Comment: My guess is that the latest Firefox is being included in this for some reason: if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) { .... I'm on an older version of FF and this version of the browser is excluded! Any ideas?

Comment: No, `nonStandardFunction` is something I made up for the example.